# Typo3 Validation with user from repository

Tags: validation, object, exception, typo3, extbase

I do have a problem with typo3 . If I get an user object from the repository which I want to update, typo3 throws me this exception if the validation fails:
[image: Typo3 exception]

First I create a new object and the validation works fine. With that „transient entity“ user-object (first picture) I
want to get the already known user („persistent“) from the repository.

When I pass the „persistent“-user to the updateAction and the validation fails I get the error
[image: my objects]

Comment: Could you share your Domain Model (Whmc\Registration\Domain\Model\User). Obviously therre went something wrong during the property mapping, which could be caused by falsy annotations.

Comment: Yes of course: http://pastebin.com/4dAzyr5w